# How do I reduce the white space under the topnav?

Tags: css

On this site http://exact-mats.myshopify.com/ we want the height of the white space above the logo to equal the height of the whitespace below it.

I can't find the CSS rule to make this happen.

I can see we need to target something in

```
<nav class="top-menu">
 ....
   <div class="row">
```

What am I missing? What CSS do I change?

Thanks.

Comment: We wouldn't see your whole website. Please refer to [how to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Need to see more of your code. CSS and HTML.

Comment: I totally understand. And I'm not sure what CSS is affecting the height of the white space. So not sure what CSS to include. As far as HTML goes, I'm not sure which elements are affecting the height either, besides the child elements of the top-menu and row class elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margin bottom from label and select inside `<div class="car-search"></div>`

```
.car-search label, .car-search select  {margin-bottom: 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

add

```
 padding-bottom: 0;
```

for the row below the div

```
<div class="free-shipping">Free shipping on all orders</div>
```

it did work when i inspected and added `padding-bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Set a height to the parent div of ".large-menu-container" which is ".row" or just add another parent to it if you don't want to modify the ".row".
I set the height to 75px and it works.
When you use "`height: 100%;`" on an element, its parent must have a predefined height in order to work.

Then you will have to adjust the select tags with a margin/padding top

Answer (score 0):

[Snapshot of new CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G7mb.jpg)

Add **margin-bottom: -30px;** In

> .top-menu .row {
>       **max-width: 82.5rem;** }

Of your **exact-mats.myshopify.com css**

If you are unable to change css because of using third party CSS then

add new CSS class in

1. Every page where you are showing your Logo

2. OR if you can, add this class to custom .css file.

> .top-menu .row {
>       **margin-bottom: -30px; !important** }

Note: I would rather suggest increasing the height of white space above top nav so it will look better than reducing space below it.
To do above thing.
Either add following CSS.

> .top-menu .row {
>       **padding-top: 31px !important;** }